# How to disable syslogger when running tests in GitLab pipeline?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, syslog-ng

I have defined tests running in GitLab cicd pipeline. I also have `syslog-ng` set up for logging. The whole app is runnning with `docker-compose`. I have defined my syslogger like this:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

def get_logger(name):
    syslog = SysLogHandler(address=("syslog-ng-container", 514))
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
    return logger
```

This works perfectly when running the app but when running tests I don't have the `syslog-ng-container` running and tests fail when trying to import the logger. I was wondering how could I disable setting the syslogger when running tests? I was thinking I could set up some variable e.g.

```
if TEST is not True:
    syslog = SysLogHandler(address=("syslog-ng-container", 514))
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
```

Can I set this variable to be `True` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` -file or do I need to specify the `TEST = True` separately in every test file I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a job runs via GitLab Pipelines, `GITLAB_CI` is set to `true`.

So something like this might be appropriate:

```
import os

if os.environ.get("GITLAB_CI")!="true":
    syslog = SysLogHandler(address=("syslog-ng-container", 514))
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
```

If you do not care about the particular value, `if "GITLAB_CI" not in os.environ:` will also work.

Although it might not be a bad idea to use a special env. variable for this use case and not depend on "GitLab Pipelines" in particular.